# How to convert Null to Empty String with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to convert Null data to an empty string. How can I do it?

Here is my column screenshot, All of them are null.

[image: column]

Here is my Stored Procedure code;

```
ISNULL(CustomerStatusId, '') AS StatusId
```

And here is my website screenshot, all of them are zero.

[image: Web site output]

Comment: If that is a **numerical** column, then an empty string will be shown as `0` ....

Comment: which data type can be show as empty string? I can change the data type.

Comment: A **string**, most likely .....

Comment: What happens when you return just `CustomerStatusId` to your website?

Comment: It's return "undefined"

Comment: That would be javascript for `null`. Now fix your javascript to stringify `undefined` as `""`.

Comment: Without any conversion what is the value of column CustomerStatusId?

Comment: It must be nothing. It shouldn't get any value.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the column has a number type of some sort.  You need to convert to a string value, even if the value is `NULL`:

```
COALESCE(CAST(CustomerStatusId as VARCHAR(255)), '') AS StatusId
```

Comment: Now I'm getting "Null" again. btw the columns data type is int.

Comment: @miracdogan . . . That really isn't possible with SQL Server.

Comment: I think it's about columns datatype.

Comment: @miracdogan . . . If you are storing this in a table, you cannot store a string value in a column that has a number data type.

Comment: So how can I print a data of varchar type blank? Whatever is written in the database, I want it as an empry string.

Answer (score 0):

If your column value id 0 then instead of IsNull please use `NULLIF` and `Coalesce()`. NULLIF(CustomerStatusId,0) will return null which will be replaced by Coalesce() with ''.

```
Coalesce(nullif(CustomerStatusId,0), '') AS StatusId
```

Comment: I'm getting 0 again. Probably about date type of column.